# Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException laravel Error

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting this error on my new Laravel project. I am trying to run after a fresh installation.

> Declaration of
>   Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface::setLocale($locale)
>   must be compatible with
>   Symfony\Contracts\Translation\LocaleAwareInterface::setLocale(string
>   $locale)

Comment: Fresh installation -- you didn't modify anything? What is the language set to in `config/app.php`?

Comment: @JeremyHarris Yes completely fresh installation. The default language is 'en'

Comment: Same issue just after building today

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: I have the same error here. It's a bigger project which runs fine locally on windows xampp. One week ago it also had no error on the server (centOS like cloud hosting OS). Today i copied the project 1:1 to the server (including vendor folder) and had this error on the server then. Also composer reinstall doesnt help. 
Local: Windows, PHP 7.2.11, works.
Server: centOS like, PHP 7.2.24, this error.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

On my server following were configurations:

PHP 7.1.26-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
Laravel Framework 5.7.28

**Solution:**
Added
`"symfony/translation": "4.3.8"` in *composer.json* as follows

```
"require": {
     ...
     "symfony/translation": "4.3.8",
}
```

and then

```
composer update
```

## or (if php version is not recommended on the server)

composer update --ignore-platform-reqs

Comment: Using PHP 7.2 also solved the problem for me without adding the "symfony/translation": "4.3.8"

Answer (score 43):

I got the same error on PHP 7.2.3 after `composer update` (symfony\translation v4.3.8 => v4.4.0).

I solved this issue with `"symfony/translation": "4.3.8"` in my composer.json.

It's a bad idea to hard edit vendors files.

--

Edit:

Symfony doc says [Install PHP 7.2.5 or higher](https://symfony.com/doc/4.2/reference/requirements.html), so if you don't want to add this restriction into your composer.json file, you can upgrade your PHP version to 7.2.5+ (check others libraries compatibility first).

Comment: I want to confirm this is the easiest and best method. Rolled mine back this morning after having issues last night and fixed it without editing any files. 

There is a defect in the 4.4 version of Symfony.

Comment: "symfony/translation": "4.3.8" not "symfony\translation": "4.3.8"

Answer (score 15):

I got the same error today and I solved it with a little editing. Just do this:
Navigate to

> vendor/symfony/translation-contracts/LocaleAwareInteface.php

and delete `string` keyword from the `setLocale()` function.

If you get this error after this:

> Declaration of Symfony\Component\Translation\Translator::trans($id, array $parameters = Array, $domain = NULL, $locale = NULL) must be compatible with Symfony\Contracts\Translation\TranslatorInterface::trans(string $id, array $parameters = Array, ?string $domain = NULL, ?string $locale = NULL)

Just navigate to:

> vendor/symfony/translation-contracts/TranslatorInteface.php

and delete all the `string` keywords from the `trans()` function

**--EDIT--**

**If you don't want to edit vendor files, you can use this:**
Open your composer.json file, and add this in `"require"`

> "symfony/translation": "4.3.8",

Then open your terminal and type this:

> composer update

Comment: Maybe it is a bug I guess. Still, I don't know the reason behind this.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a bug.

The latest version of symfony packages requires PHP version to be at-least 7.2.5

Change the PHP version to 7.2.5 or greater and it should work.

Comment: If 4.4.X requires php 7.2.5+, Composer shouldn't download the latest version if the current PHP version is less than 7.2.5, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Composer should download the package which is supported in the current PHP version.

Comment: Not true. On the server, I am using php7.3 and I still got this error

Answer (score 1):

Updating my PHP version to 7.3 works for me.

Answer (score -1):

I found simple solution to this problem after roaming google so long. If it could help someone. Upgrading your PHP Version to 7.2 or more

```
 1. sudo a2dismod phpX(X is less than 7.2 version) 
 2. sudo a2enmod php7.2(could be greater than or equal to 7.2)
 3. service apache2 restart
```

Following these steps should help you getting rid of this issue

Answer (score -1):

Update your PHP version. This often comes as a result of running `composer update` with a different version of PHP.